# No eth0 after HD transplant

Tags: ubuntu, networking, configuration

After moving the hard drive of a makeshift server to another compatible hardware (64-bit, same processor "generation", laptop->desktop) configuration, networking fails to initiate.

Specifically:

- `ifconfig` only shows `lo`
- `sudo service networking restart` shows:

-

```
stop: unknown instance:
networking stop/waiting
```

quite obviously something in the system and/or kernel is misconfigured for the new hardware setup.

**How to detect what exactly is wrong and enable `eth0`?**

The system in question is an Ubuntu 14.04 Server distro, but I suspect the problem is general.

Comment: Chances are udev is configured to set the old network card to eth0. Does ifconfig -a show anything ?

Comment: To add to what @Lawrence said: do you have a `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` file? It may have a binding from the old machine's MAC address to eth0. Comment out that line and reboot.

Comment: Your remarks were indeed on target. `ifconfig -a` showed a "stray" card on `eth1`, while a quick look at the `.rules` confirmed the origin of the problem. @MarkPlotnick , since your comment was the most helpful, could you add it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the things to look out for when cloning Linux systems is udev's persistent network device naming rules.

udev may create and update the file `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` to map MAC addresses to interface names. It does this with the script `/lib/udev/write_net_rules`. Each MAC address (with some exceptions; see `/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules`) is mapped to an interface named (by default) eth*n*, where *n* starts at 0 and goes up. An example:

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file.
#
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key.

# PCI device 0x8086:0x100f (e1000)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:0c:de:ad:be:ef",ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

Entries can be edited if you want to change the mapping, and are *not* automatically removed from this file. So interface names are *stable* even when you add additional NICs or remove unneeded NICs.
The flip side is, as you discovered, if you copy this file to another system via cloning, the new hardware's interfaces will be *added* to this file, using the first available interface name, such as eth1, eth2, etc., and eth0 will be referencing a MAC address that does not exist on the new system.

In your case, in which you transplanted the disks, you can comment out the lines containing your old hardware's interfaces, and edit the erroneous entries added due to the new hardware to have the desired interface names (or just remove them), and reboot. I initially recommended commenting them out so that when you move the disks back to the old hardware it's easy to restore, but  @Guido van Steen provided a simpler solution: mv the `70-persistent-net.rules` file to something else (but be careful about the new name if it's in the same directory!) and reboot.

Comment: Excellent elaboration on your comment, thanks :).

Answer (score 5):

Building on @mark-plotnick 's remark: The new hardware has a different mac address. The old mac address is still hard coded in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`. You could simply rename this file. In that case rebooting will recreate the file with the new mac address.

Comment: Thanks, but, to be honest, yours is basically equal to @MarkPlotnick 's comment in content, so I'm afraid I have allow him to have a go at an answer first :).

Comment: I have experienced this issue multiple times, so I had already answered you question before reading @mark-plotnick 's remark. But you are right: His remark contains the main point of my answer. His remark is a bit less decisive than mine.

Comment: To clarify - I'm not assuming ill will on your part, it's just that I actually solved the issue after reading Mark's comment, which was posted before your answer. I feel it's fair to give him a shot in this context. If he won't post an answer, I'll accept yours.

Comment: I agree that @mark-plotnick deserves the credit of answering your question.

Comment: I know it is so many years later, but this did not helped since this file is not present at all. There was an other file starting with 70-... which I have renamed and restarted but the file was still there. No new file was created.